# Changing TextView color in different xml files

Tags: android, textview

I have a ListView in one xml referencing a TextView in another xml. I'm trying to change the color of the TextView but this doesn't seem to work. If I don't set the 'setContentView' twice I got a NullPointerException.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.text_list);
          TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logText);

          if (logLevel == "E"){
              textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4D4D"));
          }
          else if (logLevel == "W"){
              textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EAAB55"));
          }
          else if (logLevel == "I"){
              textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#AFD778"));
          }
          else if (logLevel == "V"){
              textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#OOOOOO"));
          }
          else {
              textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#AFD778"));
          }

          setContentView(R.layout.log_cat);
          ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

          ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = 
                     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.text_list, log);
```

Comment: you can findviewbyid (initialize views) of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. if you don't initialize views you get nullpointer exception.

Comment: you will get always int the last else . String in java have to be comparede with equals or eqaulsIgnoreCase

Comment: also  your using setContentView(param); twice. you should re-think your app design

Comment: Good call. Using .equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// setContentView(parm ) for twice may cause problem. So If there need view from different layout then simply inflate them

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.log_cat);
      ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

       CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, "V");
           lv1 .setAdapter(adapter);
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

// custom adapter

```
   public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context ctx;
private String logLevel;

CustomAdapter (ArrayList<String> data, Context context, String log) 
{ 

     this.ctx = context;
     this.logLevel = log;
} 

@Override
public int getCount()  
{ 
    list.size();

} 

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)  
{ 
    return  null; 
} 

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)  
{ 
    return position ; 
} 

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  
{ 
     LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text_list, null);

     TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.logText);

     if (logLevel == "E"){
         textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4D4D"));
     }
     else if (logLevel == "W"){
         textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#EAAB55"));
     }
     else if (logLevel == "I"){
         textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#AFD778"));
     }
     else if (logLevel == "V"){
         textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#OOOOOO"));
     }
     else {
         textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#AFD778"));

         textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
     }
     return textView;
   }
```

}

Comment: The text is still always white. Which is what the default is because I didn't specify the color in the TextView xml. I made sure the program actually goes into one of the if statements.

Comment: i thinks textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); will work and use logLevel condition as  
initialize the logLevel value. You did not initailize the logLevel value 
logLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("V");

Comment: Still nothing. Does it matter how I set the adapter lv1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); I set it after selecting the color